# What is misconfigured when Drupal homepage works ok, but all links fail?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have recently renamed the root folder of a development Drupal site from:

www.example.com/foo/

to

www.example.com/bar/

The site stayed on the same host. During this transition, I made sure to include the .htaccess file. I also updated $base_url in sites/default/settings.php to the new filesystem path. As a result, The homepage works just fine, and all hyperlinks on the homepage go where they should ( example.com/bar/content/ ). Unfortunately, clicking on any the hyperlinks sends me to an error page:

> **Not Found**
>   The requested URL /foo/index.php was not found on this server.

This looks like a misconfiguration, but all sources I can see only site the .htaccess file and $base_url as possible points of failure. What else should I be checking? Thanks.

Comment: check your .htaccess file for URL Rewrite entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props to Shoaib Nawaz for suggesting that I look at my .htaccess file again. My RewriteBase variable within my .htaccess file was still referencing the old location.

Old configuration:

> # RewriteBase /foo

New configuration:

> RewriteBase /bar

Note that if 'foo' was a default directory name, such as 'drupal' or 'acquia', you will need to uncomment the RewriteBase line and modify it to match your new (nondefault) directory name. This was the case for me, so I didn't even think to check this aspect.

Answer (score 4):

I just looked around and found the error in my configuration.

There was a joomla Page before, and I wanted to replace it with my (local) new version (drupal) of the page.

I renamed the old directory and copied all files to the same directory again, so my vhost will work with the new drupal page.

Looking for hours, I found that in my vhost configuration I didn't allow Overriding:

```
<Directory /var/www/xxx/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    **AllowOverride None**
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

**AllowOverride None --> AllowOverride All**

And it just works... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache. You may have to do it manually in the database. Here's a page that gives a few options: http://drupal.org/node/42055. Here's another way of doing it: http://drupal.org/node/152983#d6.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Before posting this question I had cleared Drupal's cache with the devel module. Additionally I had cleared my browser's cache and used several browsers to confirm that caching was no longer part of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Which OS and database are you using?  Do you have access to the shell and a management interface for your database?

It sounds as through you have hardcoded /foo/ to various resources, and you'll have to search through your database and source files to find these settings.

I did a quick search on Google for "moving an installed drupal directory, and the from what I read, it seemed rather difficult.  It would seem that you're not only one with this issue.

http://www.google.co.uk/m/search?pbx=1&aq=f&oq=&aqi=-k0d0t0&fkt=67&fsdt=9875&q=move+an+installed+drupal+directory

Comment: OS is Debian (Lenny) and DB is Mysql (5.0). I agree that hardcoding directories in a system this complex is definitely a Bad Idea. I had to update a couple of entries within my CSS. Going 'against the grain' looks especially messy in context.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. In addition to Max`s answer, Check the httpd.conf file in the apache settings directory if rewrite module is enabled or enable it from Cpanel.

Drupal site worked but when I tried to access Drupal's back-office, I couldn't, so, in order to solve thethis issue, I`ve also enabled in the production server the following modules as they were enabled in my test server:

access_compat_module 
actions_module 
alias_module 
allowmethods_module 
asis_module 
auth_basic_module 
auth_digest_module 
authn_core_module 
authn_file_module 
authz_groupfile_module 
authz_user_module
autoindex_module 
cache_disk_module
cache_module 
cgi_module
dir_module 
env_module 
file_cache_module
include_module 
isapi_module
log_config_module 
mime_module 
negotiation_module 
rewrite_module 
setenvif_module 
userdir_module
vhost_alias_module

And finally, it worked. I hope this will be helpful. Greetings! :D